# injective *morphisms of C(D), the C^* algebra of continuous functions on the closed unit disk D

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

This question relates to one on topology and C^*-algebras that was asked two days ago, namely at the link:  [C*-algebras with no nontrivial endomorphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109772/c-algebras-with-no-nontrivial-endomorphisms)  [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109772/c-algebras-with-no-nontrivial-endomorphisms)

Let D be the closed unit disk in the plane.  Let C(D) be the unital ring of continuous complex-valued functions on D.  Then, C(D) is naturally a Banach algebra with pointwise addition and multiplication as the ring operations.  Furthermore, the "star-operation" on elements of C(D)     can be defined by: $g*(x)$ to be the complex conjugate (pointwise) of g(x), any x in D, and for any function g in C(D).

The question in reference 1 above was related to injective star-endomorphisms of some $C*$ -algebras.  Without saying so, I think the famous commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem and the Gelfand representation figured "in the background", because of the interplay of commutative $C*$-algebras and topology on compact spaces ...
If $\alpha$ is an injective star-morphism of C(D) to itself, is it possible for $\alpha$(C(D)) to be a proper (i.e. a `strict') star-sub-algebra of the $C*$-algebra C(D) ?

If so, I cannot find such a special *-morphism $\alpha$, hence my question.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Can't you take $\alpha(f)= f(g)$ where $g$ is a continuous surjection from $D$ onto $D$ that is not injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $D$ lies in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define $f:D\rightarrow D$ by $f(x):=2x$ if  $\|x\|\leq 1/2$ and $f(x):=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ if  $\|x\|\geq 1/2$. Then, $f$ is onto and continuous, but it is not injective. It is easy to see that $f^\ast :C(D)\rightarrow C(D)$ is an injective $^\ast$-homomorphism, but it is not onto.

Comment: Thanks, Vahid Shirbisheh.  I'm beginning to understand your answer.  I'm not familiar with the definition or naming of $f*$  , given $f$ .   I have heard of pull-back maps, but I don't know what they are.  The same goes for so-called "push-forward" maps.
David Bernier


Comment: $f^\ast$ is defined by $f^\ast (g) (x):= g(f(x))$ for every $g\in C(D)$ and $x\in D$.  

Comment: Thanks.  $f*$ is obtained by "pre-composing" through the map $f: D -> D$.  It's clear to me now.
